# Elasticsearch insert with nested fields works on Kibana but not with cURL

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, kibana

I am trying to insert a document in ElasticSearch which has a nested field. I have created the index by marking the field as nested using the PUT command:

```
PUT nested_test
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "nested_field": {
                     "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am inserting data into this index from Kibana Console with:

```
POST nested_test/_doc/1234
{
    "created_time": "2018-01-01 01:52:53",
    "status": "Ok",
    "nested_field": [
        {
            "col4": 0,
            "col5": 0,
            "col3": 0,
            "col1": 3234253,
            "col2": 1
        },
        {
            "col5": 0,
            "col4": 0,
            "col2": 1,
            "col1": 34241,
            "col3": 2
        },
        {
            "col5": 0,
            "col4": 0,
            "col2": 1,
            "col1": 775756,
            "col3": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

This works perfectly and I am able to see the data in the index with the nested field indexed as expected.

But if I use the same json with curl, I get an error response saying:

```
"error" : {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "object mapping [nested_field] can't be changed from nested to non-nested"
  }
```

The exact curl command used is:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://someurl:9200/nested_test/doc/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @es.json
```

Note that I have tried with both POST and PUT. 
Not able to understand why the same json on the same index works with Kibana but not with cURL. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're hitting the `_bulk` endpoint with curl, which you don't in Kibana, that's the difference. What's the exact content of your `es.json` file?

Comment: The es.json file has the same json, formatted in accordance with the bulk API specifications. es.json works if I just remove the nested_field from it, so I am sure nothing else is wrong with it.

Comment: I'm just surprised to see `experiment` in the error message while that is nowhere to be found in the JSON, so something must be off in your `es.json` file. Feel free to show it in your question

Comment: Sorry about that. nested_field was earlier called experiments. I hadn't updated the error message in my question. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem. In your mapping you are defining the `_doc` mapping type but you are using `doc` in your curl. The following curl should work:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://someurl:9200/nested_test/_doc/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @es.json
```

Comment: omg! thank you very much. This was driving me crazy. It works now.